# SQL_MODE and TIME_ZONE when creating DATABASE

Tags: mysql, sql, database, timezone, sql-mode

What do these options mean, and what are the possible choices when creating the database?

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

#------------------------------------------------------------
#        Script MySQL.
#------------------------------------------------------------

DROP DATABASE if exists BASETEST;
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS BASETEST DEFAULT CHARACTER SET UTF8 COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI;
USE BASETEST;
```

Comment: `SQL_MODE` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html `time_zone` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_time_zone.. `SET` is MySQL's way of setting system variable or user variable. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-statement.html "what are the possible choices when creating the database?" see source https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-database.html

Comment: Ok and what means time_zone = "+00:00" ? Thanks

Comment: `+00:00` means UTC timezone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-statement.html) set's one of MySQL variables. Some of them are system variables some of them are user variables ...

### SET SQL_MODE:

[SQL_MODE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html) is a system variables and you can see all possible modes in the documentation.

**`NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO`** :

> `NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO` affects handling of AUTO_INCREMENT columns. Normally, you generate the next sequence number for the column by inserting either NULL or 0 into it. `NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO` suppresses this behavior for 0 so that only NULL generates the next sequence number.

### SET time_zone :

**`SET time_zone = "+00:00"`** Sets the session timezone on [**UTC**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

Read more : [**How do I set the time zone of MySQL?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930900/how-do-i-set-the-time-zone-of-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

The [`SET` statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-statement.html) is [used here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-variable.html):

> to assign values to variables that affect the operation of the server or clients

Neither the statement nor the variables are specific to database creation. In fact I don't think they should have any noticeable effect:

- You cannot configure `AUTO_INCREMENT` handling in a per database basis (only per server or per session).
- A database does not have a time zone (the server or current session do).

It's common though that tools that generate SQL dumps set some variables to configure session and get a predictable environment to run commands. Such variables tend to come from a template and aren't customised for script content.